# Atualizando registros duplicados

Tags: mysql

Fala pessoal, tudo bem?
Então, eu fiz uma besteira de emitir boletos com o mesmo numero unico. Preciso atualizar na tabela quais são esses registros duplicados.
A query que faz essa identificação ta correta e me mostra os registros duplicados, porém na hora de atualizar, atualiza todos os registros. Não estou entendendo onde tou errando.
Valeu pessoal!!!

```
UPDATE bol_remessa set duplicado = 'S'
WHERE bol_idassociado IN(
select t.bol_idassociado 
from(
SELECT distinct rm.bol_idassociado
FROM bol_remessa rm
GROUP BY rm.bol_idassociado
HAVING COUNT(rm.bol_numerodocumento) >1
) as t
)
```

Comment: Você gerou duplicações para apenas um associado? Ou existem duplicações para vários associados diferentes? Outra questão, existem boletos anteriores para estes associados, digamos, de meses anteriores corretos? Se sim, acredito que basta adicionar uma comparação com a data de emissão dos boletos

Answer (score -1):

Tente (**sem teste**) , não usei o rm.bol_numerodocumento supondo ser a chave primária da tabela ?
Dica : defina bol_idassociado como **UNIQUE KEY**.
Obs : A sua sql **parece correta** , tentou a negativa < (COUNT(*) =1) > ?

```
UPDATE bol_remessa set duplicado = 'S'
WHERE bol_idassociado IN (SELECT rm.bol_idassociado
                          FROM bol_remessa rm
                          GROUP BY rm.bol_idassociado
                          HAVING COUNT(*) >1)
```

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui ainda.

Comment: @Joao Marcos , o que dá errado ?